# Auto-generating the column values in Excel sheet using the PowerShell commands

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, excel-interop

I have a Excel sheet in which I need to update the column values like ID from 10th row to 45th row.
I have a mixed ID "abcd_10" which needs to be extended to "abcd_45".
What are the commands to do it instead of using a for-loop. Because for-loop uses a lot of time in doing it because it points out the cell again and again and it's time consuming.
I am using this code, please tell me what's wrong in it.

```
$codeName = $currentCode
$finCode = $codeName + "_" + $i
$currentSheet.Cells.Item($intRow, $currentCol).Value2 = $finCode


$range1 = $currentSheet.Range("C10");
$r = $currentSheet.Range("C10:C45");
$range1.AutoFill($r, $currentCol)
```

`$finCode` has the initial value "abcd_10" which is inserted into the 10th row  and now I need to extend it to "abcd_45" till the 45th row. 
I have used `AutoFill` for this but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try it just with

```
$range1.AutoFill($r, 0)
```

The [second parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff195345.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) specifies the [fill type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff838605.aspx) and 0 is the default which should work in your case (I tested it only from VBA though).

---

**Update in case you are using standard COM interop:**

The following script works for me (I used some default values for unknown values).

```
$Filepath = "C:\tmp\posh\excel-interop\Book1.xlsx" 

$Excel = New-Object -Comobject Excel.Application 
$Excel.Visible = $True
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$currentSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item('Sheet1')

$i = 10
$codeName = 'abcd'
$finCode = $codeName + "_" + $i
$currentSheet.Cells.Item(10, 3).Value2 = $finCode

$range1 = $currentSheet.Range("C10");
$r = $currentSheet.Range("C10:C45");
$range1.AutoFill($r, 0)
```

Comment: @DAXholic : 0 is the column no. field so it wont work.

Comment: Please show more of your code bc currently I do not know whether you use standard COM to interact with Excel or another library